# xinetd / netcat - redirecting stdin/stdout

Tags: bash, shell, netcat, xinetd

I have a simple xinetd controlled script that wraps the simple Java application that listens on the given port.  As xinetd talks via stdin/stdout, I would like to use netcat to redirect the traffic to/from the java app.  At the moment I have the following configuration.

**xinetd**

```
service my_server 
{
   type            = UNLISTED
   disable         = no
   socket_type     = stream
   protocol        = tcp
   wait            = no
   user            = root
   port            = 2177
   log_on_success += DURATION HOST USERID
   server          = /opt/stuff/my_server.sh
}
```

**my_server.sh**

```
port=2111

# start the java process on the given port
java -jar /opt/stuff/myserver.jar "$port" &

# redirect traffic using netcat
retry_counter=0
until nc -v 127.0.0.1 ${port}
do
  let "retry_counter++"
  echo "retrying... (${retry_counter})" >> /var/log/smpp_nc
  sleep 0.1
done
```

It seems like netcat does the job of sending data to the app, but not the other way around... Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't `xinetd` take care of these things for you?  Your server should just talk to stdin/stdout and `xinetd` will connect them to the current client's socket when it establishes a connection.

Comment: Unfortunately the server cannot talk to stdint/stdout hence the need for netcat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in control of the Java server code, you're adding a layer of redirection that simply isn't needed.  Instead of configuring xinetd to call your shell script, configure it to call your Java application.  Then just use System.in and System.out from Java - it really is that simple!

Your server WILL be able to use stdin/stdout once it's hooked up to xinetd.